# Observer stream wont show all objects

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have Observer Stream with object getting from service

```
getmessages(){return this.message$.asObservable()}
```

in my view

```
 <div class="messages-left"  *ngIf="messages$ | async as message; else loading">
    <div class="slim-pageheader">
      <h6 class="slim-pagetitle">Messages</h6>
      <ion-list no-lines>
          <ion-item   >
            <ion-avatar item-left>
              <img src="">
            </ion-avatar>
            <div >
              <h3>{{message.content}}</h3>
            </div>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </div>
```

but it shows only last message not all messages stream

Comment: this is, how the Observable works. It's a stream, but in one time you can get only one value, this is not a list

Answer (score 0):

yes you are correct its working now when i change a little my methods in my service

```
messagearray  : MessageViewModel[] = []
getMessages()
```

{

this._hubConnection.invoke("GetMessages" ).then( ( messagedata : MessageData[])=> {

```
this.messagearray = messagedata;

this.message$.next(this.messagearray)
```

}).catch(err => {console.log(err)})

}

now when i have a new message from any user i  push a new message to array

```
this._hubConnection.on("MessageReceived", (message) => 
{

  this.messagearray.push(message)
  this.message$.next(this.messagearray)

})
```